# Specific .htaccess Redirect with a wildcard in the middle

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wildcard

I will preface this by saying that other posts on similar subject matter were not able help me solve this exact issue.

I am trying to rewrite the following: 

**Original**
    mydomain.com/brand-collection/{wildcard1}/{wildcard2}.html

**Rewritten to:**
    mydomain.com/{wildcard2}.html

**Example #1:**
    mydomain.com/brand-collection/sony/sony-xperia.html"
**Would be rewritten to:**
    mydomain.com/sony-xperia.html


**Example #2:**
    mydomain.com/brand-collection/sharp/sharp-aquos.html"
**Would be rewritten to:**
    mydomain.com/sharp-aquos.html

Any help is very very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have similar ones where i might find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "rewrite" then that means the browser is unaffected and the URI is changed completely on the server's end. You'd want something like this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^brand-collection/[^/]+/([^/.]+)\.html$ /$1.html [L]
```

So if the browser requests:

```
http://mydomain.com/brand-collection/sony/sony-xperia.html
```

it gets served the file that is here:

```
http://mydomain.com/sony-xperia.html
```

If there is no `/sony-xperia.html` file, then you'll just get a 404.

If you want to redirect the browser, just add the `R` flag to the square brackets.

Comment: @ThatFaucetGuy it depends on the magento rules. And how the `/sony-xperia.html` urls are supposed to be handled. Are they pages handled by magento? are they static HTML pages? Have you tried reordering the rules by purring the brand-collection rule before or after your magento rules?

Comment: Sorry i just saw your first reply now. I put it in a non magento site and had it break the original url + the new url, what can i do to test? Thanks!

Comment: I figured out my issue with the answer.. Its actually the reverse of what i need. I need if you access `http://mydomain.com/sony-xperia.html` for it to serve the file located at `http://mydomain.com/brand-collection/sony/sony-xperia.html`

Can you help me do the reverse of what is in your answer? Thanks I know this will be the fix

Comment: @ThatFaucetGuy where does the `sony` right after the `brand-collection` come from? Will it **always** be the first word in the `/sony-xperia.html` URI?

Comment: My structure will be `mydomain.com/brand-collection/[wildcard_directory]/[wildcard-page].html`

So the `mydomain.com/brand-collection` is constant but the /sony/sony-xperia.html` could be anything else. For example it could be `/samsung/samsung-galaxy.html`or `/frito-lay/doritos-cool-ranch.html`

Comment: @ThatFaucetGuy they can't be "anything" since you want to start with `/doritos-cool-ranch.html` and expand that to `/brand-collection/frito-lay/doritos-cool-ranch.html`, where does "frito-lay" come from? htaccess can only extract from the request, it doesn't know anything about what "doritos-cool-ranch" or "frito-lay" is.

Comment: I need the webserver to serve `/brand-collection/frito-lay/doritos-cool-ranch.html` when `/doritos-cool-ranch.html` is requested... The "/frito-lay/" part is a complete wildcard . My idea is that in order to keep 100 brands and their sub categories organized within one folder, i can just rewrite it to make the browser see it as originating in / instead of within the two subdirectories...
`/brand-collection/frito-lay/doritos-ranch.html --> /doritos-ranch.html` & 
`/brand-collection/sony/sony-experia.html --> /sony-experia.html`
&  `/brand-collection/xyz/xyz-donuts.html --> /xyz-donuts.html`

Comment: @ThatFaucetGuy What you are asking for is impossible, nothing mod_rewrite can do can pull a "wildcard" out of nowhere. It can't pull a "frito-lay" out of nowhere.